# Highstocks change range selector to dropdown

Tags: angular, highcharts

I need to design my highstocks similar to below with dropdown for Rangeselctor:

[image]

I followed the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rrotg5a/) code but it doesn't exactly suffice my needs. Also when user selects a range say "1M" it should show up as selected.
Currently, graph adjusts to the range selected but dropdown doesn't show current selected range.

```
exporting: {
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
      enabled: false
    },
    toggle: {
      text: 'Select range',
      align: 'left',
      height: 20,
      y: -3,
      theme: {
        'stroke-width': 0.5,
        stroke: '#000000',
        r: 2
      },
      menuItems: [{
        text: '1M',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(0, true);
        }
      }, {
        text: '3M',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(1, true);
        }          
      }]
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrapper can be used to achieve the functionality you are after, like this:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'contextMenu', function(proceed) {
    if(this.rangeSelector.selected >= 0) {
      $('.highcharts-button text tspan').text(this.rangeSelector.buttonOptions[this.rangeSelector.selected].text.toUpperCase())
    }
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); 
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

This will set the text of the button when it is clicked

```
$('.highcharts-button text tspan').text(
```

To reflect what is currently selected

```
this.rangeSelector.buttonOptions[this.rangeSelector.selected].text
```

This text will stay there until the next selection is made, therefore we have to add a function to reset it after a choice is made:

```
function resetSelector() {
  $('.highcharts-button text tspan').text('Select range')
}
```

Which is then executed when a selection is made:

```
menuItems: [{
  text: '1M',
  onclick: function() {
    this.rangeSelector.clickButton(0, true);
    resetSelector();
  }
}, {
  text: '3M',
  onclick: function() {
    this.rangeSelector.clickButton(1, true);
    resetSelector();
  }
},
```

```js
function resetSelector() {
 $('.highcharts-button text tspan').text('Select range')
}

(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'contextMenu', function(proceed) {
    if(this.rangeSelector.selected >= 0) {
     $('.highcharts-button text tspan').text(this.rangeSelector.buttonOptions[this.rangeSelector.selected].text.toUpperCase())
    } else {
      $('.highcharts-button text tspan').text('ALL')
    }
   
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); 

  });
}(Highcharts));

$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    exporting: {
      buttons: {
        contextButton: {
          enabled: false
        },
        toggle: {
          text: 'Select range',
          align: 'left',
          height: 20,
          y: -3,
          theme: {
            'stroke-width': 0.5,
            stroke: '#000000',
            r: 2
          },
          menuItems: [{
            text: '1M',
            onclick: function() {
              this.rangeSelector.clickButton(0, true);
              resetSelector();
            }
          }, {
            text: '3M',
            onclick: function() {
              this.rangeSelector.clickButton(1, true);
              resetSelector();
            }
          }, {
            text: '6M',
            onclick: function() {
              this.rangeSelector.clickButton(2, true);
              resetSelector();
            }
          }, {
            text: 'YTD',
            onclick: function() {
              this.rangeSelector.clickButton(3, true);
              resetSelector();
            }
          }, {
            text: '1Y',
            onclick: function() {
              this.rangeSelector.clickButton(4, true);
              resetSelector();
            }
          }, {
            text: 'All',
            onclick: function() {
              this.rangeSelector.clickButton(5, true);
              resetSelector();
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.highcharts-range-selector-buttons {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/973ve1sx/1/

If you just want to always show what is selected you only need to do this:

The function to set the text:

```
function setSelector(text) {
  $('.highcharts-button text tspan').text(text)
}
```

The menuoptions:

```
menuItems: [{
  text: '1M',
  onclick: function() {
    this.rangeSelector.clickButton(0, true);
    setSelector('1M');
  }
}, {
  text: '3M',
  onclick: function() {
    this.rangeSelector.clickButton(1, true);
    setSelector('3M');
  }
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/973ve1sx/9/

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks! selected value only shows after button is clicked again?

Comment: I thought that was what was desired. If you wanted to show it all the time until the next button is clicked, that is easier, no need for the wrapper function then,

Comment: Not good at putting my thoughts right. Similar to a dropdown functionality what we select is what we see. Say when I select "1M" it should show as selected in the dropdown not "select range" text.

Comment: Works. Thanks a bunch! Got to learn about wrappers in Highcharts too.